# How compiler is going to know which memory is allocated using which operator or function?

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc, new-operator

Suppose I have allocated memory for two arrays, one using `new` operator and other using `malloc` function. As far as I know both of the memories are allocated in heap segment then my question is how the compiler is going to know which memory is allocated using which operator or function? Or is there any other concept behind this.

Comment: it doesn't know. it's a runtime thing.

Comment: It is calling OS functions to do the job....

Comment: You have to keep track of it yourself.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant then why delete should not be used to the objects allocated memory and vice versa ? ultimately they'll free memory from the heap

Comment: @Vikas Because the C++ standard says so.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use `malloc` at all?

Comment: If you allocate with `malloc` constructors aren't called. If you then free the memory with `delete` it will try to call destructors and you run the risk of getting [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). Also it's [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler doesn't have to know how memory behind a pointer was allocated, it's the responsibility of the programmer. You should always use matching allocate-deallocate functions/operators. For example the operator new can be overloaded. In this case when you allocate object with new, and release it with free(), you're in trouble because free() has no idea what kind of book-keeping you have there. Here's simplified an example of this situation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct MyClass
{
    // Really dumb allocator.
    static void* operator new(size_t s)
    {
        std::cout << "Allocating MyClass " << s << " bytes.\n";
        void* res = Pool + N * sizeof(MyClass);
        ++N;
        return res;
    }

    // matching operator delete not implemented on purpose.

    static char Pool[]; // take memory from this statically allocated array.
    static unsigned N; // keep track of allocated objects.
};

char MyClass::Pool[10*sizeof(MyClass)];
unsigned MyClass::N = 0;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MyClass* p = new MyClass();

    if (argc == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Trying to delete\n";
        delete p; // boom - non-matching deallocator used.
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Trying to free\n";
        free(p); // also boom - non-matching deallocator used.
    }
}
```

If you mix and match the allocators and deallocators you will run into similar problems.

Comment: I am naive in c++ , could you tell me what do you meant by "take memory from this statically allocated array."

Comment: Look at the `static void* operator new(size_t s)`. When you do new MyClass(), this operator is called instead of the global one. It returns a pointer to an element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, both allocation mechanisms may or may not finally use the same mechanism, but pairing `new` and `free` or `malloc` and `delete` would mix conceptually different things and cause undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You must not use `delete` for `malloc` or `free` for `new`. Although for basic data types you might get away with it on most compilers, it is still wrong. It is not guaranteed to work. `malloc` and `new` could deal with different heaps and not the same one. Furthermore, `delete` will call destructors of objects whereas `free` will not.

Compilers don't have to keep track of which memory blocks are allocated by malloc or new. They might as a debug help, or they might not. Don't rely on that.

Answer (score 0):

- new/delete is the C++ way to allocate memory and deallocate memory from the heap

whereas

- malloc/free/family is the C way to allocate and free memory from the heap

I don't know why you want the compiler to know who allocated the heap memory but 
if you want to track how there is a way.

One way of doing so is `new` would initialize the allocated memory by calling a constructor you can monitor this constructor to know who allocated the memory to heap.

Regards,
yanivx

Comment: It's invalid to pass a pointer to `realloc` that was not returned from `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` or is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

It does not know. It just calls a function that returns a pointer, and pointers do not carry the information of how they got to be or what kind of memory they point to. It just passes along that pointer and does not care about it any further.

However, the function you use to deallocate the memory (i.e. `free`/`delete`) might depend on information that got stored somewhere hidden by `malloc`/`new`. So if you allocate memory by `malloc` and try to deallocate it by using `delete` (or `new` and `free`), it might not work (apart from the obvious problems with constructors/destructors).

*Might not work* in this case it is undefined what happens. This is a huge bonus for cmpiler developers and performance, because they simply don't have to care. On the other hand, the effort is put off to the developers who have to keep track of how certain memory got allocated. The easiest way to do that is by using just one of the two methods.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know both of the memories are allocated in heap segment then my question is how compiler is going to know which memory is allocated using which operator or function?

What is this thing you call the "heap segment"?

There is no such thing as far as the C and C++ standards are concerned. The "heap" and "stack" are implementation-specific concepts. They are very widely used concepts, but neither standard mandates a "heap" or a "stack".

How the implementation (not the compiler!) knows where things are allocated is up to the implementation. Your best bet, and the only safe bet, is to follow what the standards say to do:

- If you allocate memory using `new[]` you must deallocate it with `delete[]` (or leave it undeleted).
  Any other deallocation is undefined behavior.
- If you allocate memory using `new` you must deallocate it with `delete` (or leave it undeleted).
  Any other deallocation is undefined behavior.
- If you allocate memory using `malloc` or its kin you must deallocate it with `free` (or leave it undeleted).
  Any other deallocation is undefined behavior.

Not freeing allocated memory can sometimes be a serious problem. If you continuously allocate big chunks of memory and never free a single one you will run into problems. Other times, it's not a problem at all. Allocating one chunk of memory at program start and oops,  you didn't free it oftentimes is not a problem because that allocated memory is released when the program terminates. It's up to you to determine whether those memory leaks truly are a problem.

The easiest way to avoid these larger issues is to have the program properly free every single byte of allocated memory before the program exits.

Note well: Doing that doesn't guarantee that you don't have a memory problem. Just because your program eventually should free every single one of the multiple terabytes allocated over the course of the program's execution doesn't necessarily mean that the program is okay memory-wise.

Comment: the C++ std doesn't talk about any heap, it only refers to this as "Free Segment" from where the memory would be allocated dynamically. It is up to the compiler vendor to decide about how to implement this "Free Segment".